# Add 2 dollars to all product table UnitPrice's in Northwind

Tags: sql, set, currency

I know there has got to be a better way, but I haven't been able to figure out how to add two dollars to all the unit prices in the products table of the Northwind Database. The Column has the money datatype.

```
 [Code]
  -- Doesn't work, but I tried.
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  UPDATE [Products]
  SET UnitPrice = UnitPrice + 2 --Adds $2.00 to each Unit Price.
  SAVE TRANSACTION Upd_UnitPriceBy2Dol
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION Upd_UnitPriceBy2Dol
 [/Code]
```

I really tried to get this to work, but couldn't figure out how to add 2 dollars to the Northwind DB Products table in UnitPrice. I want to add 2 dollars to all of them in UnitPrice.

I get an error when I run it that says: Msg 8152, Level 16, State 2, Procedure trgProductsLog, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 177]
String or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: `I really tried to get this to work` ... what happened when you ran the update?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using `ROLLBACK`?

Comment: Yes, to roll back the transaction after. Setting the unit prices to add 2 dollars. Just to see how this works. I don't want it to be permanent.

Comment: What is trgProductsLog? Trigger on the table? Did you check UnitPrice are updated in the table and you are getting error from some other procedure which is executed internally?

Comment: Yes, Chetan, Your exactly right! There was a trigger on it and I did know! Thank you so much!

Comment: Tag the dbms used. That code is product specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about doing this?

** updated **

```
  use <databasename>

  UPDATE [Products]
  SET UnitPrice = isnull(UnitPrice,0) + 2
```

Comment: Hi maSTA, no it did not work, but thank's for trying.

Comment: can you try the updated query.. can you please confirm if you have authorization to update tables?

Comment: It was a trigger that was on the table. Your answer is really good! Thank you so much! In that even nulls would be updated to 2 dollars.

Comment: Awesome Answer!